# endfloat, float - use with newfloat types

Tags: floats

Does anyone know how I can get the the `endfloat` package to work with new float types defined using `\newfloat` (float package), for example:

```
\newfloat{map}{htbp}{lom}
\floatname{map}{Map}
\restylefloat*{map}

\newfloat{photo}{htbp}{lop}
\floatname{photo}{Photo}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Are you including `\usepackage{float}` in the preamble as I believe that is what defines `\newlfoat`.

Comment: Do you also have `figure`s and `table`s in your document? If not, it should be possible. If so, do you want everything to go to the end (`map`s, `photo`s, `figure`s and `table`s)?

Comment: Yes I am uncluding \usepackage{float} and yes I am actually using figures (no tables though)

Answer (score 4):

You need to include `\usepackge{float}` in order to be able to use `\newfloat`.

But, from the documentation it looks like [the `endfloat` package](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/help/Catalogue/entries/endfloat.html) only works with `figures` and `tables` as it explicitly looks for this name:

> Because of how the redefinitions of figure and table are actually implemented,
>   it is crucial that these environment names be used. That is, you cannot simply
>   define a new environment which calls figure or table since the former must look
>   for the literal string

---

That being said you could adapt what `\endlfoat` does to also handle the `photo` and `map` type floats (in addition to the usual `figure` and `table`). Below I have adapted it to include the `photo` float. You can further enhance this to also handle the `map` float by copying it and replacing every occurrence of `photo` with `map` and `ppp` with `mmm` (this is the extension of the .aux file that gets used).

A longer term solution would be to adapt the code in `endfloat` to be able to handle any type of float, but this should suffice for now.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{endfloat}

\newcommand{\lipsum}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In malesuada consequat mollis. Duis viverra vestibulum quam id vehicula. Donec vel tellus a orci adipiscing euismod. Suspendisse lacinia metus lorem. Vivamus pellentesque, lacus quis blandit tincidunt, elit nunc ullamcorper enim, ut laoreet metus risus sed neque. Sed ac nibh ante, pellentesque vehicula sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vel libero leo. Donec aliquam placerat arcu, et ultrices leo semper et. Curabitur dignissim, eros vitae dignissim porta, velit arcu vehicula tortor, vel blandit sapien magna in risus.}%

\newfloat{map}{htbp}{lom}
\floatname{map}{Map}
\restylefloat*{map}

\newfloat{photo}{htbp}{lop}
\floatname{photo}{Photo}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@photolist                % 
\newif\if@photohead

\@photolistfalse
\@photoheadfalse

\def\listofphotos{\@empty}
\newcounter{postphoto}
\efloat@newwrite{ppp}
\ef@newct{ppp}

\providecommand{\photoname}{Photo}
\newcommand{\photoplace}{%
   \begin{center}
     [\photoname~\thepostphoto\ about here.]
   \end{center}}

\let\@bphoto\photo
\def\photo{%
     \efloat@condopen{ppp}
     \efloat@iwrite{ppp}{\string\begin{photo*}}%
    \if@domarkers%
       \addtocounter{postphoto}{1}%
       \photoplace%
    \fi%
    \def\@currenvir{efloat@float}%
    \begingroup%
    \let\do\ef@makeinnocent \dospecials%
    \ef@makeinnocent\^^L% and whatever other special cases
    \endlinechar`\^^M \catcode`\^^M=12 \ef@xphoto}%
{\catcode`\^^M=12 \endlinechar=-1 %
 \gdef\ef@xphoto#1^^M{\def\test{#1}%
      \ifx\test\ef@endphototest
           \efloat@foundend{ppp}{photo*}
      \else\ifx\test\ef@enddblfiguretest
           \efloat@foundend{ppp}{photo*}
      \else%
          \efloat@iwrite{ppp}{#1}%
          \let\next\ef@xphoto%
      \fi \fi \next}%
}

{\escapechar=-1%
 \xdef\ef@endphototest{\string\\end\string\{photo\string\}}%
 \xdef\ef@enddblphototest{\string\\end\string\{photo*\string\}}%
}

\@namedef{photo*}{\photo}
\providecommand{\photosection}{Photos}

\newcommand{\processphotos@hook}{\@empty}
\def\AtBeginPhotos{\g@addto@macro\processphotos@hook}

\def\processphotos{%
 \expandafter\ifnum \csname @ef@pppopen\endcsname>0
  \immediate\closeout\efloat@postppp \ef@setct{ppp}{0}
  \clearpage                                                
  \if@photolist                                                      
    {\normalsize\listofphotos}                                   
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \if@photohead
     \section*{\photosection}
     \suppressfloats[t]
  \fi
  \markboth{\uppercase{\photosection}}{\uppercase{\photosection}}%
  \processphotos@hook \@input{\jobname.ppp}
 \fi}

\renewcommand{\processdelayedfloats}{{%
  \def\baselinestretch{1}\normalsize
   \let\figure\@bfig
   \let\table\@btab
   \let\photo\@bphoto
   \processdelayedfloats@hook
   \if@tablesfirst \processtables\processfigures
   \else \processfigures\processtables \fi
   \processphotos
   \processotherdelayedfloats}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{photo}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{myPhoto}
    \caption{My Photo 1}
\end{photo}
\lipsum
\begin{photo}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{myPhoto}
    \caption{My Photo 2}
\end{photo}
\lipsum
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{myFigure}
    \caption{My Figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\begin{map}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{myMap}
    \caption{My Map}
\end{map}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice. I coded some [`endfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) trickery for the smaller case where one can substitute a `figure`/`table` for something else.

Comment: I did not think it was going to be that hard, but once I got into it I kept going...  I started looking into providing a means of adding a new float type it, but sure does not seem easy.

Comment: Yes. That's why it seemed to be an author-wish-list candidate. It would be neat to specify all your code using a macro-like approach by issuing something like `\newendfloat{<float>}{<ext>}`.

Comment: Will adapt my `newfloat` package to the `endfloat` package the upcoming week-end...

Comment: This is really fantastic. Thank you so much.

Comment: However I am having trouble making it work with my paper. Everything works in the minimum example, even when I use my entire preamble, but when I run it on the full paper something bugs. I will add the error message on another comment. Any ideas about this?

Comment: Here is the error in the log `[2] [3 <D:/Data/Wp_files/Articles/history_nq/fig/glacial_bp.jpg>]
(Denton_history_v5.fff) [4] (Denton_history_v5.ppp))
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> ...s/Articles/history_nq/Denton_history_v5.tex
                                                  
? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> ...s/Articles/history_nq/Denton_history_v5.tex
                                                  
End of file on the terminal!`

Comment: Sorry, can't pinpoint the problem with just the error message.. I can't claim I fully understand the code posted here as it was basically cut and paste from `endfloat.sty`, and I do recall seeing error messages similar to that as I was adapting it. To fix them I found the missing parts of the `endfloat.sty` that I had not adapted to the `photo` float. The only thing that comes to mind is if you are trying to generate a list of the `photo` floats similar to a list of `figure`s. If so, please update the MWE to include that and if that reproduces the problem, I can try to get that to work also.

Comment: No, I did not add command to produce a list of photos. Endloat appears to assume that you want a list of figures. The list appears automatically. I wonder if there is a clue here.

Comment: But if it was an automatic thing it would have occurred in the MWE. I think it is best if you try to reduce your full document down to a MWE that reproduces the problem, and perhaps post a new question. Sorry that I can't be more helpful.

Comment: Regarding the `newfloat` package: It tourned out that I would need redefining half of the `endfloat` package. Since this would not make much sense, I decided to revise the `endfloat` package instead, and got the permission from Jeffrey Goldberg (current maintainer) to put it to CTAN afterwards. This approach also added even more benefit to the user since this will not only work with my `newfloat` package but with the `float` and `floatrow` package as well. (See my answer)

Answer (score 4):

When using the `endfloat` package v2.5 one can use `\DeclareDelayedFloat` to make new floating environments known to the `endfloat` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{float,endfloat}

\newfloat{map}{tbp}{lomap}
\floatname{map}{Map}
\DeclareDelayedFloat{map}{Maps}

\begin{document}

\begin{map}
\centering
\includegraphics{x}
\caption{A map}
\end{map}

\end{document}
```

Version 2.5 (which offers support for longtables, threeparttables etc. as well) is currently under test by the questioner. If you are interested in testing this version, too, please drop me a e-mail.

Addendum: Version 2.5 is available on CTAN and as TeXlive and MikTeX update right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you limit your new floats to two<sup>*</sup> (say, `map`s and `photo`s) and you don't have any `figure`s or `table`s, then you can trick [`endfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) into thinking that you're working with `map`s and `photo`s by merely using `figure` for `map` and `table` for `photo` (plus the appropriate redefinition of certain commands).

First you would define your new floats `map` and `photo` using the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) interface. Additionally, you would redefine `\listoffigures` to be `\listof{map}{List of Maps}` and `\listoftables` to be `\listof{photo}{List of Photos}`. Then, use `\begin{figure}[..] ... \end{figure}` whenever you want a `map`, and `\begin{table}[..] ... \end{table}` whenever you need a `photo`. You also need to use `\captionof{<newfloat>}[..]{...}` to obtain a caption for the new float.

Here is a minimal working example illustrating this fact:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage[nomarkers]{endfloat}% http://ctan.org/pkg/endfloat
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\usepackage{float}% http://ctan.org/pkg/float
\begin{document}
% ========== MAP FLOAT ==========
\newfloat{map}{htbp}{lom}% \begin{map}[htbp]...\end{map}
\floatname{map}{Map}%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\listof{map}{List of \fname@map s}}
\makeatother
% ========== PHOTO FLOAT ==========
\newfloat{photo}{htbp}{lop}% \begin{photo}[htbp]...\end{photo}
\floatname{photo}{Photo}%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\listof{photo}{List of \fname@photo s}}
\makeatother

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering\includegraphics{map1}
  \captionof{map}[Beautiful]{This is a beautiful map.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{table}[p]
  \centering\includegraphics{photo1}
  \captionof{photo}[Amazing]{This is an amazing shot.}
\end{table}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering\includegraphics{map2}
  \captionof{map}[Awesome]{This is an awesome map.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{table}[p]
  \centering\includegraphics{photo2}
  \captionof{photo}[Stunning]{This is a stunning picture.}
\end{table}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) was used to modify the layout, while [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provided dummy text. Additionally, the `demo` option passed to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) was used to replace all images with a 150pt x 100pt black rectangle (for compatibility purposes).

---

<sup>*</sup>If this is not the case, then more trickery would be needed. This includes the possibility of using new floats in addition to `figure` and `table` (not just a replacement), or using more than two new floats, or a combination of both.

The last possibility is mentioned on the package author's "wish list", although it has not been implemented, and may likely not be under the current maintainer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using "figures" as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jeffrey Goldberg and Axel Sommerfeldt, that made the two packages compatible, it's currently trivial (from [`endfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) docs):

```
\usepackage{newfloat,endfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{map}
\DeclareDelayedFloat{map}{Maps}
```

A more complete example:

```
\usepackage{newfloat,endfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=lsf,
    listname={List of Supplementary Figures},
    name=Supplementary Figure,
    placement=p,
]{supfig}
\DeclareDelayedFloat{supfig}{Supplementary Figures}
```